# Xcode compiles iPhone app for Debug not Distribution - Linking error "file not found"

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution

Xcode compiles my iPhone app for Debug fine and the application works fine on my iPhone.  But when I compile for Distribution I get the following Linking error:

```
/Users/jtesta/Documents/WaterTaxi_prod_v1.1/build/WaterTaxi.app/WaterTaxi
ld: file not found: 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's not clear to me what file is not found.  It almost looks like it can't find the executable in the application bundle.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas which maybe you already tried?

- Do a clean rebuild of absolutely everything
- Make sure you have the proper provision profiles setup on your computer and on the iPhone

Did you try searching stack overflow for this error?  I got the following hit...

[QtCreator build returns collect2: ld returned exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485239/qtcreator-build-returns-collect2-ld-returned-exit-status-1)

There is also some discussion about this issue here...

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/96529-error-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status.html